# Autoscroll from source not working correctly in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, autoscroll, intellij-14

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14 Community Edition, and I have "autoscroll from source" active in the Project View.

In my project, I have the directories:

> /src (contains all .java source files)
>
> /classes (contains all compiled .class files)

What I expect autoscroll to do is to scroll in the Project View to the source file (.java file in the /src directory) that is currently active in the editor.

My problem ist that sometimes the view does not scroll to the .java file but to the .class file in the /classes directory. This seems to happen randomly and it's very annoying.

Is there a way to fix this issue or is it an IntelliJ bug?

Comment: Sounds like IntelliJ bug. Report it on youtrack.jetbrains.com. You'll probably have more chance to get some useful feedback on it there than on SO

Comment: Autoscroll to/from source has never worked reliably in any JetBrains products and it probably never will.